# Filtering array of nested arrays object in Typescript

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, filter

I am having some trouble to filter nested array data set. For example I have list of data array below:

```
let list = [
{
  "percentage": 50.0,
  "budget": "online",
  "ruleName": "C1"
},
{
  "percentage": 50.0,
  "budget": "offline",
  "ruleName": "C1"
},
{
  "percentage": 50.0,
  "budget": "other",
  "ruleName": "C4"
}
```

]

Now I want to achieve following result using **.map** or **.filter** and considering the condition if the budget property of **parent array** and **child group array** matches then it should return only matched **object** inside **group** instead all:

```
[
  {
    "budget": "online",
    "ruleName": "C1",
    "group": [
        {
            "budget": "onlne",
            "percentage": 50.0
        }
    ]
  },

  {
    "budget": "offline",
    "ruleName": "C1",
    "group": [
        {
            "budget": "offline",
            "percentage": 50.0
        }
    ]
  },

  {
    "budget": "other",
    "ruleName": "C4",
    "group": [
        {
            "budget": "other",
            "percentage": 0
        }
    ]
  }
```

]

So I performed below action but my result didn't match to my expected result above:

```
this.group = list.map((i)=>{
  return {
    budget: i.budget,
  }
})
this.payments = list.map((i)=>{
  return {
    budget: i.budget,
    amtPercentage: i.percentage ? i.percentage : 0,
    rulename: i.rulename,
    group: this.group
  }
})
```

Here is following result after above code execution:

```
[
{
    "budget": "online",
    "ruleName": "C1",
    "group": [
        {
            "budget": "onlne",
            "percentage": 50.0
        },
        {
            "budget": "offline",
            "percentage": 50.0
        },
        {
            "budget": "other",
            "percentage": 0
        }
    ]
},

{
    "budget": "offline",
    "ruleName": "C1",
    "group": [
        {
            "budget": "onlne",
            "percentage": 50.0
        },
        {
            "budget": "offline",
            "percentage": 50.0
        },
        {
            "budget": "other",
            "percentage": 0
        }
    ]
},

{
    "budget": "other",
    "ruleName": "C4",
    "group": [
        {
            "budget": "onlne",
            "percentage": 50.0
        },
        {
            "budget": "offline",
            "percentage": 50.0
        },
        {
            "budget": "other",
            "percentage": 0
        }
    ]
}
```

]

I don't have any clue how to filter the nested group array based on the condition where if parent array budget property equals to group.budget property then it should return only that object but not all.

I'll be very grateful for your help. Many thanks in advance.

Note: I am using typescript with angular-2.

Comment: Hi .. I suggest to you this library : `https://github.com/kutyel/linq.ts`

with this you can archive your goal

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but may be I can consider this in my next project.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
this.payments = list.map((i)=>{
  return {
    budget: i.budget,
    amtPercentage: i.percentage ? i.percentage : 0,
    rulename: i.rulename,
    group: this.group.filter((x) => i.budget === x.budget)
  }
})
```

EDIT simplification:

```
this.payments = list.map((listElement) => ({
    ...listElement,
    amtPercentage: listElement.percentage || 0,
    group: this.group.filter((groupElement) => listElement.budget === groupElement.budget)
}))
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution but I get group as empty array. See below:

[
  {
    "budget": "online",
    "ruleName": "C1",
    "group": []
  },

  {
    "budget": "offline",
    "ruleName": "C1",
    "group": []
  },

  {
    "budget": "other",
    "ruleName": "C4",
    "group": []
  }
]

Comment: Is `this.group` empty then? The filter just picks the elements from `this.group` which has the `budget` value as the current element(`i`).

Comment: Yes correct and how it suppose to work but still empty and I don't know why?

Comment: It works now ... it was stupid typo I didn't noticed. Thanks again for saving my day. Cheers!!!

Comment: No problem:) Feel free to click the checkmark(✓) next to my answer to accept it as the correct answer.